How to configure web security configuration in spring boot based on http servlet request
How to configure web security configuration in spring boot based on http servlet request. Below is my configuration class. I want to skip JWT authentication based on request header value. if header has sourceSystem and it's value is External then skip JWT authentication else JWT authentication is required.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
// configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load user for matching credentials Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
    
auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
urls.add("/test");
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

if (null != request.getHeader("sourceSystem") && "EXTERNAL".equals(null != request.getHeader("sourceSystem"))) {
urls.add("v2.0/inspection/getClaimInspMetaData");
}
String[] arr = new String[urls.size()];
arr = urls.toArray(arr);

// We don't need CSRF for this example
httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
    // dont authenticate this particular request
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(arr).permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll(). //For Bypassing the JWT Validation in Optional Request
    // all other requests need to be authenticated
    anyRequest().authenticated().and().
    // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
    // store user's state.
    exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
//httpSecurity.cors();
//web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
// Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
httpSecurity.cors();
}
}


Please add the configuration class you mentioned in the question

@pochopsp I added configuration class

Does this answer your question? what's the proper way to add Spring Security filter only for specific URL?
